# Is it possible to modify the Contacts using URI and cursorLoader instead of ContentResolver() insert() , delete() modfiy() etc

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and trying to add an activity that would let me manipulate the contacts without going to the contacts app.

I used a cursorLoader() to access the the Contacts and displayed it in a listView.
Now I want to insert, delete or edit a new contact .

My question is do I have to use ContentResolver().insert() for this or is there a way to do it using CursorLoader() itself. Is CursorLoader() just for accessing data ?

I do see examples to do this using ContentResolver() but wondering if that is not recommended anymore ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

CursorLoader is indeed intended for just accessing data.

It's implementation helps you keep the data in your activity/fragment updates during it entire life cycle (it knows when to stop, restart, start etc.).

The insert command is an atomic command, there's no reason to wrap it in a Loader, it's a bit overhead for this simple action (but still needs to be executed in a new task)

Comment: Thank you for the response. So I can use CursorLoader() for accessing the data and use ContentResolver() to manipulate the contacts